# Draw text on Bitmap with fixed position

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-bitmap, drawtext

I'm trying to draw two Text on bitmap using the code below, everything works fine, but I have a problem with the size of the bitmap if the size small the position of text changed, for example

**1080x1920**

[image]

**250x268**

[image]

Code :

```
public Bitmap drawTextToBitmapVHS(Context gContext,
                                      Bitmap bitmap) {
        String PLAY = "PLAY ►";
        String DATE = getDate(Calendar.getInstance());
        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig =
                bitmap.getConfig();
        if (bitmapConfig == null) {
            bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        double relation = Math.sqrt(canvas.getWidth() * canvas.getHeight()) / 250;
        paint.setTextSize((float) (12 * relation));
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/VCR.ttf"), Typeface.BOLD));
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(DATE, 0, DATE.length(), bounds);
        int horizontalSpacing = 24;
        int verticalSpacing = 36;
        int x = horizontalSpacing;
        int y = bitmap.getHeight() - verticalSpacing;
        canvas.drawText(PLAY,
                x, bounds.height() + verticalSpacing, paint);
        canvas.drawText(getHours(Calendar.getInstance()), x, y - 50, paint);
        canvas.drawText(DATE, x, y, paint);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

How I can make the texts fixed although the size of the bitmap exactly like the first image (1080x1920), Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with your hardcoded spacings and possibly your calculation of text size.  If you make these relative to the bitmap sizes, it may help, e.g.:

```
int horizontalSpacing = 24 * bitmap.getWidth() / 1080;
int verticalSpacing = 36 * bitmap.getHeight() / 1920;
```

This should set the positions to the same as for the 1080x1920 bitmap, but for small bitmaps you will probably find your text overlapping unless you similarly adjust text size relative to the bitmap height:

```
paint.setTextSize((float) (70 * bitmap.getHeight() / 1920));
```

Also your positioning of the time field is hardcoded and would need to be changed:

```
int hoursOffset = 50 * bitmap.getHeight() / 1920;
canvas.drawText(getHours(Calendar.getInstance()), x, y - hoursOffset, paint);
```

Taken together this will draw the text in the same relative positions and size as per the 1080x1920 bitmap.